# bash script using espeak only says first word

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-to-speech, espeak

I am writing a bash script to convert lyrics to audio clips using espeak.
The problem is that espeak only says the first word, rather than the line by line that I'm reading. I tried putting the lines in the file with quotes, but this did not fix the problem.

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="$1"
##input="/path/to/txt/file"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
  espeak -k cantonese $line

done < "$input"
```

Here is the text file line by line:

```
"Work it"
"Make it"
"Do it"
"Make us"
"Harder"
"Better"
"Faster"
"Stronger"
```

How can I make espeak say every word?

Please note that every word is said, when I read from a file using the `-f` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
espeak -k cantonese $line
```

Use:

```
espeak -k cantonese "$line"
```

When you omit the [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes) around `$line`, the shell performs [**word splitting**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) on the result of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), and each word is passed as a separate command-line argument to `espeak`. The `espeak` command only speaks the first argument. Writing `"$line"` instead of `$line` suppresses word splitting, causing all the text stored in the `line` parameter to be passed as a single argument to `espeak`. (It also suppresses [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion), which is another thing you don't want to happen in this situation, though your test inputs have most likely not triggered it so far.)

This happens even in simpler uses of `espeak`. For example, `espeak hello world` says just "hello," while `espeak 'hello world'` or `espeak "hello world"` says "hello world."

As for what [*kind* of quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) to use, the reason to write `"$line"`, rather than than `'$line'`, is that [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) are too powerful for what you need. They would suppress word splitting and globbing, but they would *also* suppress parameter expansion. So with `'$line'`, the `espeak` command would see the literal text `$line` instead of whatever text is held in the `line` parameter.

Comment: On a side note, it would make sense to report this to espeak's developers and ask them to process every parameter rather than just the first one.